# How convert linux command CURL to PHP

Tags: php, linux, curl

I want to convert this linux command console to PHP code, to send data via curl,

```
curl -X POST -d 'data[][street]=1' link.....
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$fields = 2;
$fields_as_string = "key=value&key2=value"    

//open the curl connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
// set the number of post fields
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, $fields);
// set the fields
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_as_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

Don't forget to make sure you've enabled the curl php extension.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PHP cURL Library.](https://php.net/curl)

```
    <?php
    //initializing the connection.
    $connection = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.yoursite.com");
    curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query(array('postvar1' => 'value1')));

    // receive server response ...
    curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $server_output = curl_exec ($connection);

    curl_close ($connection);

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried PHP cURL library? ;)

https://php.net/curl

PHP documentation always gives nice examples.